# jquery able/disable button when click items

Tags: jquery

I'm making the list-items, and when I select(click) items, the button turn to enable button from disable button.
I just tried well, but the problem is when I dis-select item, the button is not turn to disabled.
How do I have to fix the script ? Please help~

Here is fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/RUgsH/

And this is the codes

```
<div class="boxList">
                     <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-ajax="false"><span>item1</span></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-ajax="false"><span>item2</span></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-ajax="false"><span>item3</span></a>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-ajax="false"><span>item4</span></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-ajax="false"><span>item5</span></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" data-ajax="false"><span>item6</span></a>
                        </td>  
                    </tr> 
                    </table>
                </div>



<div class="popBtnWrap2">
                    <a href="#" class="btnSchd1 ui-disabled">Button</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btnSchd2 ui-disabled">Button</a>
                </div>

                $('.boxList td').on('click',function(){ 
                    $('.popBtnWrap2 a').removeClass("ui-disabled"); 
                    var $this = $(this); 

                    if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
                        $this.removeClass("selected");
                    }else{
                        if ($('.boxList td.selected').length !== 3){
                            $this.addClass("selected");
                        }
                    }
                }); 



.boxList table { table-layout:fixed; width:100%; border-spacing: 2px; border-collapse: separate; margin:0; padding:0; }
.boxList td { width:33.3%; padding:0; margin:0; text-align:center; background:#f4830b;}
.boxList td.selected a { background:#cc471e;} 




.popBtnWrap2 { overflow:hidden; margin:20px 0 0 0;  }
.popBtnWrap2 a { display:block; float:left; width:-webkit-calc(33% - 5px); width:-moz-calc(33% - 5px); width:calc(33% - 5px);  }
.popBtnWrap2 a:last-child { width:34% !important; margin:0 !important; }
.popBtnWrap2 .btnSchd1 {  background:#434343; }
.popBtnWrap2 .btnSchd2 {  background:#434343;   }

.ui-disabled { opacity:0.4; }
```

Comment: like http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/3RDqV/1/ ?

Comment: what is the purpose of the condition where you are checking for !==3

Comment: or http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/3RDqV/2/ ?

Comment: @Arun P Johny / Wow! I'm going to use like length<3 to 1. Anyway  this is what I want. thank you for your help~ :)

Comment: see my answer below... instead of `length < 1` you can use `length == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.boxList td').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
        $this.removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        if ($('.boxList td.selected').length < 3) {
            $this.addClass("selected");
        }
    }
    $('.popBtnWrap2 a').toggleClass("ui-disabled", $('.boxList td.selected').length == 0);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/3RDqV/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ToggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) from JQuery. Serves this purpose well.

A [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Q2P3T/) has been forked from yours.

Hope that is what you needed.

```
$('.boxList td').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("selected");

    var selections = $(".selected");

    if (selections && selections.length > 0) {
        $('.popBtnWrap2 a').removeClass("ui-disabled");
    } else {
        $('.popBtnWrap2 a').addClass("ui-disabled");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do this with less code

```
    $('.boxList td').on('click',function(evt){ 
        var $this = $(evt.currentTarget);
        $this.toggleClass("selected", 
                      !$this.hasClass('selected') && 
                      $('.boxList td.selected').length < 3);
        $(".popBtnWrap2 a").toggleClass("ui-disabled", 
                      $('.boxList td.selected').length==0);
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonycheung/RUgsH/3/)